# Windows Wireless Drivers - Install

Tags: wireless, dual-boot, software-center, adapter, netgear

I have nearly ended my journey of making a dual-boot windows xp and ubuntu computer. Along with version 12.04, came the problem with my NetGear WNDA3100v2 wireless adapter. It wasn't compatible. My last step in my adventure is to install the software called Windows Wireless Drivers.

I have internet access on my laptop and a flash drive. It would be preferable to receive a link to this program, because I see no link on the website, and I can't download it from the Ubuntu Software Center. Thanks.

Comment: In your search journey did you see this thread from ubuntuforums.org ? [Netgear WNDA 3100 v2 wireless adapter -- How to install?](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1964173)

Answer (score 0):

Software Center says that program is actually "ndisgtk" to which Synaptic (or the website) lists these dependencies:
ndiswrapper-common
ndiswrapper-utils-1.9

So from Windows you should be able to download your original Windows driver and these debs: (select the one for your computer 32/64 bits)

- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/ndiswrapper-common
- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/ndiswrapper-utils-1.9
- http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/precise/main/base/ndisgtk

Install the DEBs in the order I have the downloads above by double-clicking, then run "ndisgtk" or "Windows Wireless Drivers" (whichever one appears in the run dialog type-ahead).

Comment: It says "Dependancy is not satisfiable: python-glade2

Comment: i need a link to manually install Windows Wireless Drivers because I don't have internet access on my main computer due to me not having Windows Wireless Drivers. Please provide a link to this. I already have ndiswrapper and things like that. I only need the Windows Wireless Drivers package. Please Help!!!